# Spark Map and collect

Tags: python, serialization, apache-spark, pickle, pyspark

I have a multiple 2-D numpy arrays in my parallelized RDD and I call a map function that does operations on the numpy arrays and returns back a 2-D numpy array, but when I call collect on it, I get an Assertion Error. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

```
class JacobiNd(Stencil):
    def __init__(self, dimensions, radius, use_moore=False, backend='c', boundary_handling='clamp', **kwargs):
        if use_moore:
            neighborhoods = [Neighborhood.moore_neighborhood(radius=radius, dim=dimensions, include_origin=False)]
        else:
            neighborhoods = [Neighborhood.von_neuman_neighborhood(radius=radius, dim=dimensions, include_origin=False)]
        super(JacobiNd, self).__init__(backend=backend, neighborhoods=neighborhoods, boundary_handling=boundary_handling, **kwargs
        self.neighbor_weight = 1.0 / len(neighborhoods[0])

    def kernel(self, in_grid, out_grid):
        for x in self.interior_points(out_grid):
            out_grid[x] = 0.0
            for y in self.neighbors(x, 0):
                out_grid[x] += self.neighbor_weight * in_grid[y]

stencil = JacobiNd(dimensions = 2,radius = 1).kernel
define jacobi_spark(twoD_data):
    out = np.zeros_like(twoD_data)
    stencil(twoD_data,out)
    return out
twoD_jacobi_rdd = sc.parallelize(partitioned_twoD_data,twoD_partitions)
test_run = twoD_jacobi_rdd.map(lambda x: jacobi_spark(x))
print test_run.collect()
```

What stencil does is that given a 2-D array that is passed in if I run this command:

```
out = stencil(twoD_array_data)
```

I get a new 2-D array

Assertion Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File.py", line 90, in <module>
    print test_run.collect()
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 188, in __repr__
    return self._jrdd.toString()
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2351, in _jrdd
      pickled_cmd, bvars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(self.ctx, command, self)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2271, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 427, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 622, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 485, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 353, in save_global
    self.save_reduce(typ, (obj.__name__, obj.__bases__, d), obj=obj)
  File "/home/S/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 504, in save_reduce
    self.memoize(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 244, in memoize
    assert id(obj) not in self.memo
  AssertionError
```

---

Solution: I just needed to put the class JacobiNd into its own file. Not exactly sure why though, but it worked. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: What's the assertion error say?

Comment: It would be useful if provide the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It means example input and `stencil` code.

Comment: The way your code is written - stencil is an instance of the JacobiNd class. You need to point it to the kernel method like this - stencil = JacobiNd(..).kernel   You can then pass it to the map function.

Comment: I made edits to my code and I still get the same AssertionError. I'll update the edits on the question.

Comment: Everything worked, apparently I just needed to put the class JacobiNd into its own file. Not exactly sure why though. Can anyone explain?